# form not getting submitted on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, post, onclick

I am trying the submit the form on button click but want user to confirm whether he is sure or not. 
I have mutiple submit button on form and I just want pop-up in case of delete. 
When I make the type of my button submit. My form gets submitted twice If I confirm else It gets submitted once (I don't want it to submitted in that case).

I have multiple form on the page. That's why I am trying to submit the form getting parent Node and not using getElementbyId.

JavaScript function

```
function deleteEvent(btn){
      var confirmed=confirm('Do you want to delete the event?');
      if(confirmed){
          var f = btn.parentNode;
          f.submit();
          }
      else{
          return false;
          }
    }
```

HTML Code

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" onClick ="deleteEvent(this)">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Working Solution:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onClick ="return confirm('Do you want to delete the event?');">
```

Comment: if the input is of type submit it will continue unless you use event.preventDefault or any of the other methods to stop the form from submitting.

Comment: That's why I made it type of button, but then I am not able to submit it.

Comment: you could place an ID for the form and using that you could submit it instead of using parent

Comment: @Varada But I am getting the form object, then submit should work ?
I am generating multiple similar forms on run-time, so anyway I have to find the "form" from parent of button only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

use **onclick="return deleteEvent(this);"** if button type is submit

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" onclick="return deleteEvent(this);">
```